# how to calculate the derivative of a finite series in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to sympy and I want to calculate the derivative of a finite series with variables in two periods. For example, I tried the following code:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Sum, diff, IndexedBase, Idx

T = symbols('T', interger=True)
t = symbols('t', interger=True)
β, σ = symbols('β σ')
a = symbols('a', cls=IndexedBase)

L = Sum(β * a[t] + σ * a[t + 1], (t, 0, T))
print(diff(L, a[t]))
```

I got the results like `Sum(β, (t, 0, T))`. But in fact, my expectation is β+σ. Why? Because a[t] appears two times in this series. One is β * a[t] (when time=t) and another is σ * a[t] (when time=t-1).

How could I get the expected result with sympy? Thanks

Comment: How would sympy know how `a[t]` and `a[t+1]` relate to be able to take the proper derivative? From sympy's perspective, those are two independent variables.

Comment: Also, to create beta and sigma, it would be more proper to do `beta, sigma = symbols("\\beta \\sigma")` (that uses LaTeX notation to create the variable properly). When displaying in a jupyter notebook, those variables will be rendered in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a sum the summation variable is a bound dummy variable i.e. the Sum as a whole is not really a function of `t` just like `Integral(x, (x, 0, 1)) = 1/2` is not really a function of `x`. It does not make sense to use the same symbol `t` outside of the sum when it is not free in `L`.

Instead use a different symbol:

```
In [25]: L
Out[25]: 
  T                        
 ___                       
 ╲                         
  ╲                        
  ╱   (β⋅a[t] + σ⋅a[t + 1])
 ╱                         
 ‾‾‾                       
t = 0                      

In [26]: L.diff(a[n])
Out[26]: 
  T                        
 ___                       
 ╲                         
  ╲   ⎛β⋅δ    + σ⋅δ       ⎞
  ╱   ⎝   n,t      n,t + 1⎠
 ╱                         
 ‾‾‾                       
t = 0                      

In [27]: L.diff(a[n]).doit()
Out[27]: 
⎧β + σ  for T ≥ n ∧ T ≥ n - 1 ∧ n ≥ 0 ∧ n ≥ 1
⎪                                            
⎪  β              for T ≥ n ∧ n ≥ 0          
⎨                                            
⎪  σ            for T ≥ n - 1 ∧ n ≥ 1        
⎪                                            
⎩  0                  otherwise
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a further related question. I once get the similar result using L.diff(a[1]). I am wondering what is the δ? What do the two subindex of δ (n,t) mean?

Comment: It's Kronecker delta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta